# Docker + docker-compose up + Cannot start service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, rhel, confluent-platform

we have docker-compose.yml that contain configuration for `Kafka` , `zookeeper` and `schema registry`

when we start the docker compose we get the following errors

```
docker-compose up -d


Starting kafka-docker-final_zookeeper3_1 ... error

ERROR: for kafka-docker-final_zookeeper3_1  Cannot start service zookeeper3: network dd321821f3cb4a715c31e04b32bff2cf206c85ed5581b01b1c6a94ffa45f330e not found

ERROR: for zookeeper3  Cannot start service zookeeper3: network dd321821f3cb4a715c31e04b32bff2cf206c85ed5581b01b1c6a94ffa45f330e not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

and

```
systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-03-19 07:57:29 UTC; 1h 55min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 12105 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 30
   Memory: 654.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─12105 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Mar 19 07:57:29 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T07:57:29.610005717Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Mar 19 07:57:29 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T07:57:29.631338594Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Mar 19 07:57:29 master3 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 19 07:58:12 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T07:58:12.352833676Z" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: re...ng headers)"
Mar 19 07:58:12 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T07:58:12.352916724Z" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/...ng headers)"
Mar 19 07:58:12 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T07:58:12.353019409Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.22/images/create returned error: Get https://registry-1.do...ng headers)"
Mar 19 08:03:47 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T08:03:47.255058871Z" level=warning msg="error locating sandbox id 20ce3c5b6383ad92dae848c3de1d91bbfff9306ca86fdc90fae...c not found"
Mar 19 08:03:47 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T08:03:47.263976715Z" level=error msg="ef808aa411ae0aaef0920397c77b6d9a327bdd1651877402fe1fc142a513af8a cleanup: faile...h container"
Mar 19 09:50:43 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T09:50:43.920457464Z" level=warning msg="error locating sandbox id 20ce3c5b6383ad92dae848c3de1d91bbfff9306ca86fdc90fae...c not found"
Mar 19 09:50:43 master3 dockerd[12105]: time="2020-03-19T09:50:43.927744636Z" level=error msg="ef808aa411ae0aaef0920397c77b6d9a327bdd1651877402fe1fc142a513af8a cleanup: faile...h container"
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

regarding to

```
Cannot start service zookeeper3: network dd321821f3cb4a715c31e04b32bff2cf206c85ed5581b01b1c6a94ffa45f330e not found

Cannot start service zookeeper3: network dd321821f3cb4a715c31e04b32bff2cf206c85ed5581b01b1c6a94ffa45f330e not found
```

how to fix this issue?

```
docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
6c729cb0bb2c        confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   3 months ago        Exited (255) 2 hours ago   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   kafka-docker-schemaregistry_1
ef808aa411ae        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest         "/etc/confluent/dock…"   3 months ago        Exited (255) 2 hours ago   

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES


docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                         DRIVER              SCOPE
e5566ab8ca6d        bridge                       bridge              local
2467d9664593        host                         host                local
c509e32d0d67        kafka-docker-default         bridge              local
08966157382c        none                         null                local
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `docker network ls`?

Comment: I update the question , thank you

Comment: I should have asked in the previous comment, but do you define network in compose file? Logs indicate that something is wrong with network. Perhaps start services without `-d` flag to see what's going on from the beginning. Maybe even posting whole logs. It's very difficult to tell what could be the issue from information you posted.

Comment: if you mean that I defined the ip address in docker-compose.yml then yes  , also try without "-d" but the same errors

Comment: Can you post you compose file and logs when you start services with `docker-compose up`? The more information we have, the faster we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we fixed the issue by the following procedure

```
#  docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
6c729cb0bb2c        confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   3 months ago        Exited (255) 5 hours ago   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   kafka-docker-schemaregistry_1
ef808aa411ae        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest         "/etc/confluent/dock…"   3 months ago        Exited (255) 5 hours ago                            kafka-docker-zookeeper3_1


# docker container rm 6c729cb0bb2c
# docker container rm ef808aa411ae


systemctl stop   docker
systemctl start   docker

docker-compose up -d
Creating kafka-docker-zookeeper3_1 ... done
Creating kafka-docker-kafka3_1         ... done
Creating kafka-docker-schemaregistry_1 ... done




docker-compose ps
               Name                            Command            State                                   Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kafka-docker-kafka3_1           /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
kafka-docker-schemaregistry_1   /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp
kafka-docker-zookeeper3_1       /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2888->2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3888->3888/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for me it was enough to:

```
sudo docker-compose down
sudo docker-compose up
```